# Pulling cell text based on multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10I_0xtV2SlBObJxh_WF-fDgmS_PlNqUBDp4csy-Olzg/edit#gid=315204817)

In trying to add ingredients from the data page if the "need it!" drop down is selected and no "got it!" options are selected in the category ie: beans, fruit,...

the best i am able to do s select all "need it!" with

```
=QUERY(Data!$A$2:$C, "select A where C='Need It!'", 1)
```

but i don't want the categories that contain "got it" so the only result im looking for is chicken eggs.

Comment: sorry i just made it public, could you take a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check if this (rather convoluted) formula works ?

```
=iferror(query(ArrayFormula({filter(Data!A2:A, Data!C2:C="Need It!"), isna(match(filter(Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C="Need It!")&"Got It!", query(Data!B2:B&Data!C2:C, "select* where Col1 contains 'Got It!' "), 0))}), "select Col1 where Col2 =TRUE "))
```

Comment: thanks but it still seems to list just the "need it!" put it on the diet page.

Comment: Seems like I forgot two sheet references. Formula is updated now. Can you check again ?

Comment: Just tested it on a copy of your sheet and the present formula seems to output the expected result. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: G.E.N.I.U.S. Works like a charm. thank you. if you have another minute im trying to add max grams able to purchase without spoilage  next to the item. example:   chicken eggs | 1149.12g <-- ((Cal from diet page 78.25)*(shelf life 21)/(cal/100g 143)*100=1149.12. also i might try to divide that if 2 or more items are needed in the same category. obviously if you dont get around to this i am very thankful for the first favor.